# Checking Current Domain and for a PHP Variable + Condensing Code

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is check the current domain for 2 different domains + some variables so currently I have this:

```
    if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example1.com" && $var1 || 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example1.com" && $var2 || 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example1.com" && $var3) {
            header("Location: page1.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        }

    elseif ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example2.com" && $var1 || 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example2.com" && $var2 || 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example2.com" && $var3 ) {
            header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        }
     else { echo "..."

}
```

I only have 3 variables for each, but in total I have 10 so what would be the best way to condense this code so I don't use so many lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the HTTP condition every time.

```
if($var1 || $var2 || $var3) {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "example1.com") !== false) {
        header("Location: page1.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    } elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"example2.com") !== false) {
        header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    } 
}
```

or you can do it in 2 single lines.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "example1.com") !== false && ($var || $var2 || $var3) {
    header("Location: page1.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

Comment: In Joe Bobby's code the else-code is also run if none of var1,var2,var3 is true.

Comment: Yea then its a mix from our both answers.

Comment: @Stony getting the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&'` with the bottom code.  I tried it jsut with 1 `$var` to see if that would solve anything but it didnt

Answer (score 0):

```
$else = false;
if($var1 or $var2 or $var3) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "http://example1.com") {
        header("Location: page1.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    } elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example2.com") {
        header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    } else {
        $else = true;
    }
} else {
    $else = true;
}
if($else) {
    echo "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if($domain == 'http://example1.com' && ($var1 || $var2 || $var3)){
    header("Location: page1.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}elseif( $domain == 'http://example2.com' && ($var1 || $var2 || $var3)){
    header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}else{
    echo "..."
}
```